# Is またね OK even if I don't literally expect to see them again?

Tags: meaning, greetings

After a casual conversation with strangers, is it ok to use またね, even though I don't literally expect to see them again? バイバイ and さよなら feel too Englishy to me, and I assume "see you" is still English, not Japanese. However, I am happy to repeat バイバイ and "see you" if said by the other, usually Japanese, person.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is odd that you say またね to strangers whom you don't expect to see again.

I think それでは、じゃ、では、失礼します are appropriate in the situation.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, but I don't fully understand. Aren't じゃ and では short forms of phrases which would include また, and therefore be equally logical or illogical?

Comment: じゃ and では aren't short forms of phrases which would include また. We can say では、失礼します. Of course, you can say では、また but it has the same meaning of またね.